# bulk update with EF, what is the best way?

Tags: entity-framework

I need to update in bulk, it is pretty much the below sql statement

```
update RECORDS set SOMEValue = 1 where ID in (1, 5, 3,6,7,9)
```

I have written the following which works

```
  //get all the records to update
    var COESRecord = context.COESDetails.Where(x => model.COESs.Contains(x.COESNo));           

    foreach (var COES in COESRecord)
    {
         COES.InspectorId = model.InspectorId;
         context.Entry(COES).State = EntityState.Modified;                
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
```

But the issue is when i am updating 1000 records it just takes a long time.  Is this the best way to do it? or is there another way to do bulk updates?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay away from SQL you can try with [EntityFramework.Extended](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2011/11/29/entity-framework-batch-update-and-future-queries.aspx).

Provides support for writing LINQ like batch delete/update queries. I only tried it once, it worked nice, but not sure if i would use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of right off hand to achieve what you are seeking.

1) create a stored procedure and call it from your entity model.

2) Send the raw command text to the db, see this [microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx)

Comment: by sending a raw command do i need to be worried about sql injection attacks?

Comment: Yes, anytime you send raw text to the db you need to be concerned about sql inection